# How to join multiple rows in single pandas dataframe by common key column (fixed length limit)?

Tags: python, pandas

How can you join multiple rows in single pandas dataframe by common key column where we let there be a fixed length limit for any combined row of rows (as the number of rows with a given common key in this case is variable)?

Have a dataframe of a form like...

```
key x1 x2 x3
-------------
1   a1 a2 a3
1   b1 b2 b3
2   c1 c2 c3
3   d1 d2 d3
3   e1 e2 e3
3   f1 f2 f3
3   g1 g2 g3
....
```

and would like to change it to something like

```
key x11 x12 x13 x21 x22 x23 x31 x32 x33
-------------
1   a1  a2  a3  b1  b2  b3  NA  NA  NA
2   c1  c2  c3  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
3   d1  d2  d3  e1  e2  e3  f1  f2  f3
....
```

where column xjk is the kth feature of the jth row having the same key as the other rows grouped in this same row up to (in this case is manually set to...) 3 per group (but may want to change later and **may be a value greater than the amount of groupable rows** (eg. 5 here) in which case it should just fill with NAs). Notice that when there are less than the max limit of individual original rows to group we fill the values with NA and when there are too many rows we group only up to the max limit of rows and drop the rest from the dataframe. Also note that sometimes an individual row may have missing values.

Any suggestions on how this could be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and then [`ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) to flatten all values inside a group:

```
lim = 5

df = df.set_index('key')
k = len(df.columns)

x = df.groupby(level=0).apply(
    lambda z: z.iloc[:lim].values.ravel().tolist() +
    [np.nan]*(lim*k-z.size))

x = pd.DataFrame(x.tolist(), x.index)

x.columns = [f'x{1+i//k}{1+i%k}' for i in x.columns]

print(x)
```

Output:

```
    x11 x12 x13  x21  x22  x23  x31  x32  x33  x41  x42  x43  x51  x52  x53
key                                                                        
1    a1  a2  a3   b1   b2   b3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2    c1  c2  c3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3    d1  d2  d3   e1   e2   e3   f1   f2   f3   g1   g2   g3  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks. Note for others using this question, note that the last line's string formatting for labeling the columns will only work in python 3.6+, if still using python 2.7 need to use `'x{}{}.format((1+i//len(x)), (1+i%len(x)))'`.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I missed that requirement. Updated my answer with `lim` variable that sets this limit. We basically need to take the first `lim` rows in the apply with `.iloc[:lim]`

Comment: @lampShadesDrifter: And thanks, it's a very good point about the f-strings in python 3.6

Comment: Oddly, this code does not seem to be working for me (using python 2.7) a test dataframe made to be like the that in the original question. Getting column labels: `x11 x12 x13 x14 x15 x16 x17 x18 x19`. I think the last line in the given code should be something like: `x.columns = [f'x{1+i//len(df.columns)}{1+i%len(df.columns)}' for i in x.columns]`. That then gave me the results shown in this answer.

Comment: Looking at the code and looking at the stats on my actual use case data, I don't this this answer actually works for the requirement that the max limit may be a value greater than the amount of groupable rows (which I realize now was not explicit in the original question and really illustrated the best in the example case). Note, my actual use case has rows with ~33 columns each that are trying to combine (~7 individual rows per combination).

Comment: That's right, please see the updated version. It fixes the column names and allows the `lim` to exceed the number of grouped rows found in the dataset (tested with 5 on the test data)